# How to postpone AJAX request after typings in the input ends

Tags: jquery

I am still very new to jQuery and I am using ajax to redirect to a different php file that puts information into a database table via POST.  The problem is if a user is entering something into the field it would be updated on every keypress.  This entry is actually in an html table so I do not want a button to press when finished.  I dont want to trust a click out or mouse off because if the user enters something and gets called away from his desk it may be hours before he is back and clicks out for the info to send.

**My question is: How could I change my jQuery to work better, instead of connecting back out to the database on every keystroke.**

I thought maybe a combination of a click out and a timer would be a nice catch all, but I am not sure how I would do this?  That way it allows for the user to immediately click to another `<td>` and keep working, but if they would happen to get up and walk away from their computer, after maybe 5 seconds of no typing at all, the information would be updated on the database.  Here is the current jQuery I am using:

```
            $('td').on('input',function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "updatedatabase.php",
                data: { 
                    content: $(this).text(), 
                    date: $(this).siblings().first().text(),
                    prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                    old: old
                }
            })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( msg );
            });
```

Backround on this code, any td is clickable as anything can be modified on the table.  When the `<td>` is clicked content editable is added allowing the `<td>` to be modified.

Comment: So inside the `td` is an `input` field? Wouldn't work the `blur` event for you? This triggers only when the user is finished typing in the input field

Comment: Use a timer and only trigger the AJAX after a delay of X seconds. Clear the timer after every keydown for example.

Comment: Look up debouncing.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like the following fairly often

```
var saveTimeout = false;
$('input').on('input', function() {
    if(saveTimeout) clearTimeout(saveTimeout);
    saveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        //Do Ajax call here
    }, 500);
});
```

This will check to see if there is a current timeout running and if it is, it'll cancel it, meaning the ajax call won't happen. If they don't fire the `input` event within the 500ms, it'll send off the ajax request.

Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: This makes sense and works great when doing a basic test with it.  For some reason it is affecting my post results when I add Ajax into it though?  I threw the old working code, and the modified code using your code to see if you could possibly tell me why the old version sends POST fine, but the new version doesnt, thank you.
http://jsbin.com/xosokawimi/edit?js
http://jsbin.com/xaqigigijo/edit?js

Comment: @Brandon, you can't use `$(this)` inside the timeout as this refers to the timeout function. Before the `setTimeout` function add `var $el = $(this)` and then swap out `$(this).index()` with `$el.index()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Underscore library and look for [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function. This function will postpone its execution after waiting defined milliseconds since the last time it was invoked.

```
$('input').on('keypress', _.debounce(function() {
    alert('Fires after typing end with 500ms delay');
}, 500));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp47g8zh/1/)

Example with AJAX

```
$('input').on('keypress', _.debounce(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "updatedatabase.php",
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( msg );
    });
}, 500));
```

Comment: Note that this uses an additional library. Debounce as used here is not a standard javascript or jquery function.